# Initializing References and Variables In C++

Tags: c++

Given the following c++ function:

```
int& ReturnAReference() {
   /* Do something here */
}
```

Is there any difference between the two statements:

```
int normalVariable = ReturnAReference();
int& referenceVariable = ReturnAReferene();
```

Is one version preferred over the other?

Comment: @Floris Yes, they do.  Checked in visual studio 2012.

Comment: Both of them are not assignments (strictly speaking) but initializations.

Comment: @DyP Should I change the title?

Comment: I believe #1 would still involve a copy

Comment: Well the difference between *assigning* to a reference and *initializing* a reference is an important part of an answer to your question.

Comment: Bad idea to return references IMO.  Pass the thing you want as a reference in the parameter list and you've removed a whole lot of chance-to-fail from your life.  Think about what would happen if you returned a reference to something on the stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding this:

```
int normalVariable = ReturnAReference();
```

`normalVariable` is an integer, and is assigned the value of the int that `ReturnAReference()` references.  As such incrementing, assigning, or doing anything else to `normalVariable` will not affect whatever `ReturnAReference()` has internally.

Regarding this:

```
int& referenceVariable = ReturnAReference();
```

`referenceVariable` is a reference to an integer that would otherwise be internal to `ReturnAReference()`.  As such incrementing, assigning, or doing anything else to `referenceVariable` *will* affect whatever `ReturnAReference()` has internally.

What is preferred depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but in many cases the second approach (using `referenceVariable`) violates "encapsulation" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming) ), which is considered poor design.

EDIT:  And I should add that if ReturnAReference() is returning a reference to a variable that is local in that function, that reference will be invalid as soon as ReturnAReference() returns.

Comment: I would argue that it is returning a reference in the first place that violates encapsulation, and not the `referenceVariable` in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

After a reference has been *initialized*, e.g. via

```
int i = 42;

int& r1 = i;
int& r2 = ReturnAReference();
int& r3(i);
int& r4{i};      // C++11
int& r5 = {i};   // C++11
```

it becomes an *alias*, i.e. another name, of the object it has been initialized with. It is *not* another integer. <sub>Note that in the language of the C++ Standard, an object is simply a region of storage, not necessarily an instance of a class.</sub>

As a reference is an alias, if you operate with the reference, you'll operate *on the original object* (the one it has been initialized with):

```
int i = 42;
int& r = i;
// r is now an alias for i, both refer to the same object
r = 21;  // a true assignment
std::cout << i; // will print 21
```

The statement

```
int normalVariable = ReturnAReference();
```

introduces a new object of type `int` and a name for that object: `normalVariable`. This object is initialized with the object returned by `ReturnAReference()`, which means that the value of the returned object is copied into the new object called `normalVariable`.

On the other hand, the statement

```
int& referenceVariable = ReturnAReferene();
```

only introduces a new name for the object returned by `ReturnAReference()`.

---

If your function would return a non-reference `int`, like `int ReturnAnInt();`, the statement

```
int& r = ReturnAnInt();
```

would become illegal, as the object returned by this function is a *temporary*, which only lives until the end of this line (in this case). In the next line, the name `r` would refer to an object that does not exist any more, so it has been made illegal to bind non-const references to temporary objects.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have the following definitions :

```
int test = 4;

int& ReturnAReference() {
   return test;
}
```

1) Is there any difference between the two statements:

```
int normalVariable = ReturnAReference();
```

In this case, `normalVariable` will hold a copy of the return value (not a reference), because the assignment operator copies the value referred by the return value into `normalVariable`.  This means that after

```
normalVariable = 1;
```

`normalVariable` will now be 1, but `test` will still be 4.

However, if you were to have written

```
int& referenceVariable = ReturnAReferene();
```

and do

```
normalVariable = 1;
```

`normalVariable` would now be 1 and `test` would also be 1, since `normalVariable` is only an alias for `test`.

Be careful though when you return a reference.  For instance, if you were to do

```
int& ReturnAReference() {
   int i = 0;
   return i;
}
```

the reference returned from `ReturnAReference()` would not be valid anymore, since it is only valid inside the function and will be destroyed when it is exited.

2) Is one version preferred over the other?

In the case of ints or other primitive types, I would prefer the `int` return value over `int&`, simply because an `int` is small and won't be expensive to copy (it will nearly always fit in a register).  Also, the `int&` return value entails safety issues if the reference refers to a local variable.  For classes or structs, it always depends, but you have to be careful when returning local variables by reference or by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the variable returned by reference from the function, or to keep track of any changes to its value, use int&. It's up to you to make sure the variable you are referencing will exist for as long as you access it. If you just care about the value of the variable returned by reference at that point, use int.

FYI, std::vector's operator [] and `at` functions return by reference allowing syntax such as the following `v.at(0) = 2`.